# How do I set ggplot stat_summary geometry to a specific y value?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

I have compact letter display on a line graph but I'm not happy with how the group letters are at different heights. I would like to have them all aligned along a specific y value. How do I accomplish this?

[image: Graph]

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = dose.log, y = positif.prop.total)) +
  geom_point(color="grey", size=1) +
  xlab(expression(log[10]~x+"0.001")) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,1)) +
  ylab(" ") +
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="point") +
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="text", label=c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c"), size=5, vjust=-2) +
  geom_smooth(method='lm', color="black", formula = y ~ poly(x,1)) +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = my.formula, aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")), parse = TRUE) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme_pubr()
```

Comment: Why not `geom_text(aes(x = dose.log, y = 0.75, label = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c")))`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (10): label is what is returned. How do I tie it to the stat_summary for mean?

Comment: Aha, I did not know there were multiple obs per dose. (Though it makes sense as a motivation for using stat_summary.) Then I'd suggest `x = unique(dose.log)` to winnow it down to just the 5 x values.

Comment: No worries, I didn't provide enough info for you to deduce that :). It does not appear that geom_text is accepting the ```unique()``` argument, as I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: ```mapping = aes(y = 0.75)``` ended up being my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution I was looking for.

```
stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="text", label=c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c"), size=5, mapping = aes(y = 0.75)) +
```

The difference from before is I removed the `vjust` nudge and replaced it with `mapping = aes(y = 0.75)` to specify the exact y coordinate for my `stat_summary` text geometry:

[image]